# Memory Increase in OpenGL Rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem about C++ project with memory increasing in the OpenGL rendering. The project is generating a video, it use OpenGL to render all the frames of video. So I have a system with about 30k atoms to render, and here is the part for rendering atoms:

```
    glPushMatrix();

    if(bBlend)
    {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }//Enable blend effect, normally bBlend will be false.

    //create quadric surface object institude

    for(i=0;i<nTotal;i++)
    {
        if(i%nMod!=0) continue;//nMod normally wil be 1, this one is irrelavant

        iAtomSeq=pList->GetAt(i).iSeq;
        clr=getAtomColor(iAtomSeq,iAtomType);//*/get color data for atom

        if(bBlend) glColor4f(clr.red,clr.green,clr.blue,alpha); 
        else        glColor3f(clr.red,clr.green,clr.blue);

        glPushMatrix();

        pos=m_aClust.getPosData(iAtomSeq,bOrig);// Atom postion
        glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z);

        radius=getAtomScaleRadius(iAtomSeq,iAtomType);
        glScalef(radius,radius,radius);

        glCallList(elementList[QUA_SPHERE].getListID()); 
        glPopMatrix();
    }//loop for rendering atoms

    if(bBlend) glDisable(GL_BLEND); 
    glPopMatrix();
```

Basically, after the loop for rendering 30k atoms, task manager shows that the memory usage will increase about 1.8MB.

I want to figure out the reason of memory usage increasing and fix it. The project uses double buffering for rendering the frame. I tried to use `glutSwapBuffers` and `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)`. But that didn't work, as the project is based on Win32, using `glutSwapBuffers` will encounter an interruption.

Comment: Are you saying that every time you run the loop you get an extra 1.8MB? Or do you mean that you get this additional memory once, and then it doesn't really go up after that? If it's the latter, it's likely something internal to OpenGL or something else your program is using. Possibly even the memory allocator itself. Unless you have a leak, you shouldn't really be worrying about something like this.

Comment: @paddy I gets an extra 1.8MB every time I run the loop

Comment: Try progressively removing things from the loop until you no longer get the leak. It's hard to say what's going on here because there's a bunch of your own functions with mystery implementations. Use a process of elimination to isolate the primary cause.

Answer (score 1):

In obsolete versions of OpenGL as you're using, OpenGL allocates a lot of memory internally. It's required, because everything must be buffered to be accessed on modern GPU. In your case it's geometry data that use pass using `glColor4f`.

We don't have open source code of OpenGL driver for Windows, but we can check implementation for Linux that ideologically must be the same. In [vbo](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/tree/main/src/mesa/vbo) folder of Mesa source code you can see how obsolete OpenGL draw commands are processed. In a nutshell, all geometry data are mapped to internal vertex buffer objects (VBOs).

The best you can do here, is to avoid using obsolute OpenGL. In any version marked as Core Profile, you can allocate your own explicit VBOs, use them to draw your geometry and release them when you've done with them.

EDIT: if you have a persistent leak (memory increasing every frame), OpenGL code that you demonstrated doesn't look related to it.